# Javascript | HTML5 XHR XMLHTTPRequest Streaming a Video as Blob file as it is being downloaded

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a issue with streaming video as blob file using javascripts HTML5 blob support.

What I wanted to achieve was live streaming the blob file with javascript before it is fully downloaded / preloaded in the browser. (That way clicking Play instantly starts instant playback)

It should stream as a blob file but instead clicking "Play" on the video box / container results in a XHR 200 ok response and then nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
<video controls="" preload="auto" id="_video">
<source src="" type="video/mp4">
<source src="" type="video/webm">
<source src="" type="video/ogg">
</video>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var video_id = "_video";
var video_url = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4";
var video_type = "video/mp4";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', video_url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
//xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

xhr.onload = function() {
document.getElementById(video_id).src = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
//document.getElementsByTagName('source')[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response); // this does not work don't know why
/*need to check if webm or ogg or MP4 and make the output one of them */
};
</script>
```

What I was expecting to be able to do was when I visit the page Click play and the video should start streaming as a blob. But I do not seem to get any errors or issues so I am a bit dumbfounded as to what the problem is.

Comment: Funny code ;-) : you are loading the resource as a Blob, then read it as a dataURL, treat like if it were an arrayBuffer to convert it to a blob at the end. Replace everything in `xhr.onload` with `document.getElementById(video_id).src = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);`

Comment: Sometimes I wonder why people do not just set it as the source to begin with.

Comment: @epascarello to load the whole media is one quite good reason.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank's for the information i tried that but same dilemma I get no video playback but still the xhr 200 ok status. Do I also Have to wait for the entire video file to be downloaded as blob or I can start streaming it as a blob with what ever bytes i already have. It does play but not straight away it seems to play after the video has fully downloaded as a blob not what I was aiming to achieve since I was expecting to (stream) as blob bytes being still being received.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me... xhr.reponseType = "blob" is only able to fetch whole Files. No Partial Content there. So yes, you have to download the whole video, but it should be done when the xhr.onload handler fires. If you don't want to download the whole file, then indeed, why don't you set the video's src to the url of the file directly ?

Comment: And if you really need to get a stream-like feature from a static file on your server, but that you don't know how to setup a streaming service server-side, maybe you are looking for the [MediaSource API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource), but its fetched as arrayBuffers, not as Blob. Once again, a Blob represents a whole File. But by looking at what you wrote in your question, I'm pretty sure you'll just get more confused getting this path... So please forget about it, may help future readers but you, use `<video src="yourfile.mp4"></video>`

Comment: But that was what I wanted to try to achieve or see if was possible was instead of having src="yourfile.mp4" is to be able to stream with XHR I wanted to basically have no src set and let XHR and Javascript relay and play the contents as it was receiving it. (No waiting functioning the same but with Javascript being the one serving the content live) If that makes sense it may seem pointless but it is what I wanted to see if was possible.

Comment: So yes it's possible, with the MediaSource API.